# Visual Studio 2017's intellisense doesn't recognize ASP Tags anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

In my solution for Visual studio 2017, my intellisense doesn't recognize asp tags anymore and it won't autocomplete any despite doing so previously. Though, when i build and compile it'll run the asp tags normally. This doesn't halt my development, but it does hinder it by slowing me down so i'd like it to be resolved. Though, unfortunately, none of the solutions i found online prove to be a remedy. The inability to recognize asp tags also tends to differ from webpage to wepage within the solution, only some pages recognize the `<%@Page>` and `<asp:Content>` and `<%# Master>` tags while all webpages don't recognize tags like `<asp:Button>` but they autocomplete the properties for it like `runat='server'` or `OnClick='<insertfunctioname>'` They generate a green underline stating this: `Validation (XHTML5) Element '<Insert Tag>' is not supported`

I tried many solutions all to no avail, i'll list a few below:
1. Deleted the ReflectedSchema folder and reset computer / visual studios
2. Checked my Master page for specific changes and applied recommended changes to it to no prevail
3. Wiped and Re-pulled my entire project from my shared repository, my colleagues have no issues but mine still persist.
4. Downgraded visual studios to a previous version / Reinstalled visual studios altogether
5. Uninstalled then reinstalled asp.net packages individually and as a package
6. Changed my project's target asp.net framework to an older version
7. Cleaned and Rebuilt the solution
8. Temporarily deleted the files I worked on in particular within the solution, problem still persisted though.
9. Tried to change the project settings so that HTML5 would work with Asp, though apparently my settings were already set to the intended target settings.
10. Reset the Settings through Export / Import Settings in Tool Drop down. 

11. Repaired visual studio using visual studio launcher.

12. Deleted hidden vs folder in solutions folder

I'll also include interesting facts i found when trying to go about solving my dilemma 
Interesting facts: 
1. Any new solutions i make will have intellisense working normally.
2. Changing the project's target asp.net framework fixed it temporarily, but after a few seconds the error reemerged. Then after switching back and forth, if i was previously on said target framework, the window where the error didn't emerge never occurred anymore.
3. No one else who downloads the project, even after I push my changes onto the repo, suffers the same problem. 

Anyone else mind recommending a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the hidden .vs folder under the solution folder?

Comment: I just tried it, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Please backup your solution and remove this tag: <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"> from the project file to have a test.

Comment: Where would i go about finding that tag within the solution? Because i used the search for option for my entire solution and the tag doesn't appear.

Comment: @Sara Liu - MSFT : I unloaded the project and tried to find the tag in the .csprog file, but i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem, in my case html tags have working intellisense, asp net tag however only shows one item "db". I've tried reverting to previous commit, etc; none works.

The fix, oddly enough, was to remove references to some assemblies and re-add them.
One thing I noticed was the project file now flags those referenced assembly files with "Specific Version" set to False.

Other things I did was Clean project and manually deletes everything in "bin" and "obj" folder (deletes them into Recycle Bin in case needed).